# 'dd' raw drives to lvm is inefficient. Is there a better way?

Tags: proxmox

I have a proxmox installation.
I'd like to import a vmdk to a lvm and the procedure is:

```
$ qemu-img convert -p -f vmdk "IE11 - Win7-disk1.vmdk" -O raw "IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw"
```

and then:

```
$ dd if="IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw" bs=1M|pv| dd of=/dev/mapper/pve-vm--103--disk--1
```

And that works fine.

But there are 8.8GB data on a 127GB virtual drive:

```
$ qemu-img info "IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw"
image: IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw
file format: raw
virtual size: 127G (136365211648 bytes)
disk size: 8.8G
```

**And when I "dd" the raw drive I see 127GB copied when only 8.8G of them matter.**
And that's painstakingly slow.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at the `bs` paramater to increase the side of each 'chunk' that `dd` copies?  e. g. `dd if=/path/to/input of=/path/to/output bs=128M`.

Comment: I usually do bs=1M, but the problem is not that, but the fact that it copies 127GB instead of 8.8GB. I'll update the question and add the bs.

Answer (score 3):

A faster way is not to use `dd`

```
pv < "IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw" > /dev/mapper/pve-vm--103--disk--1
```

The fastest is to use `cat` directly

```
cat "IE11 - Win7-disk1.raw" > /dev/mapper/pve-vm--103--disk--1
```

Your invocation of `dd` was using 512 byte blocks, which would result in two system calls reads per KB, or ~2000 per MB. With `cat` you'll probably get away with one per MB.

Comment: OP  is using `bs` as 1M.

Comment: Fine, my use of `dd` was not particularly optimal. Still all these commands, copy all the data from the `.raw` file, which is 127GB. And the actual data there is 8.8GB. Probably there is a smarter import option not using dd at all.

Comment: Actually there's some indication that `pv < file > dev` might be somehow be skipping the blank spaces in the `.raw` because I saw data rates like 1.6GB/sec for more than 4 seconds. Will investigate further

Comment: @heemayl not when I answered the question they weren't. But I see now there's an edit that's added this in.

Answer (score 2):

I was migrating from XenServer to Proxmox and I figured out this solution.

First get a qcow2 file if you don't already have it (You may need to use a different command here if your source file is not a raw disk image, the important thing is to get a qcow2 file as result)

```
qemu-img convert rawimage.img -O qcow2 thinimage.qcow2
```

Covert the qcow2 image to raw [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file):

```
qemu-img convert -p -f qcow2 -O raw -t none -T none thinimage.qcow2 rawsparce.raw
```

Write the sparse file to the VM's thin lv:

```
dd if=rawsparce.raw of=/dev/mapper/pve-vm--100--disk--1 bs=8M conv=sparse status=progress
```

Answer (score 1):

RAW format supports only preallocation, that's why you got full size disk when you converted by `qemu-img`.

Try convert `vmdk` image file to `qcow2` format, witch can work without preallocation.